# how to write jdbc url?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle12c

oracle database is 12c,

I use java and  write  like `url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.203.10:1521/pdbcems`,

but get error

`java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor`

My pdbs is like this,

```
SQL> select con_id,dbid,NAME,OPEN_MODE from v$pdbs;     

CON_ID       DBID NAME                           OPEN_MODE
```

---

```
     2  510431291 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY
     3 1955806753 PDBORCL                        MOUNTED
     4 2032327615 PDBCEMS                        MOUNTED
```

and lsnrctl is like this,

```
oracle@trace:~$ lsnrctl status    

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.203.10)      (PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------   

Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.203.10)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=trace)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/u01/app/oracle/admin/orcl/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "orcl.localdomain.trace" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "yz", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB.localdomain.trace" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "yz", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "pdbcems.localdomain.trace" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "yz", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "pdborcl.localdomain.trace" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "yz", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

I cannot find the way solve this problem.

how to write the `url` string.

Comment: URL syntax is here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm#BEIDHCBA.  Yours looks okay; can't tell what credentials you passed.

Comment: Which service name is reported by `select name, con_name from v$active_services` for the PDB you are trying to connect to?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe service name you are making use of is not valid. Just to crosscheck this below query will give you list of services. Kindly make sure you are using correct service name.

```
select value from v$parameter where name='service_names';
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the pluggable database and after change nls_characteset, I just startup database and forget open PDB.silly mistake!

Comment: PDB's. Open  mode should be 'open write'